# Установка расширения в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, makefile

Я пытаюсь установить расширение для PostgreSQL на ArchLinux. Но вызов команды `make USE_PGSX=1` приводит к ошибке: `make: *** No rule to make target '/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.`. Я устанавливал базу данных из исходного кода, и у меня есть папка `contrib`, но как можно прописать к ней путь?

Comment: Вы хотите contrib ставить или полностью стороннее расширение?

Comment: Стороннее: https://github.com/postgrespro/rusmorph